# Image Detection Open CV

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

So I'm trying to draw a rect around an image. I'm finding a sub image from a larger image using Open CV. How I calculated it was to convert both the template image (target) and the target image (scene) to HSV and get the back projection of the object and compare it with the scene image which is saturated. Works a bit. (Would be glad for any improvements). Basically i want to draw a rect around the image and extract the found rect from the scene unto a Mat. I've tried a doing it a couple of ways but doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code. My question is how do I get the sub image from the target image?

```
public List<DMatch> subListGoodMatches(List<DMatch> good_matches) {
        Collections.sort(good_matches, (DMatch o1, DMatch o2) -> {
            if (o1.distance < o2.distance) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o1.distance > o2.distance) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        if (good_matches.size() > 10) {
            good_matches = good_matches.subList(0, 10);
        }

        return good_matches;
    }

    public List<Mat> calculateHistograms(Mat image) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        List<Mat> hsv_planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        Core.split(image, hsv_planes);

        MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(256);
        final MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);
        boolean accumulate = true;

        Mat h_hist = new Mat();
        Mat s_hist = new Mat();
        Mat v_hist = new Mat();

        //Break channels
        List<Mat> h_plane = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        List<Mat> s_plane = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        List<Mat> v_plane = new ArrayList<Mat>();

        h_plane.add(hsv_planes.get(0));
        s_plane.add(hsv_planes.get(1));
        v_plane.add(hsv_planes.get(2));

        Imgproc.calcHist(h_plane, new MatOfInt(0), new Mat(), h_hist, histSize, histRange, accumulate);
        Imgproc.calcHist(s_plane, new MatOfInt(0), new Mat(), s_hist, histSize, histRange, accumulate);
        Imgproc.calcHist(v_plane, new MatOfInt(0), new Mat(), v_hist, histSize, histRange, accumulate);

        //Draw combined histograms
        int hist_w = 512;
        int hist_h = 600;
        long bin_w = Math.round((double) hist_w / 256);

        Mat histImage = new Mat(hist_h, hist_w, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        Core.normalize(h_hist, h_hist, 3, histImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
        Core.normalize(s_hist, s_hist, 3, histImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
        Core.normalize(v_hist, v_hist, 3, histImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
            Point p1 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(h_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
            Point p2 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(h_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
            Core.line(histImage, p1, p2, RED, 2, 8, 0);

            Point p3 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(s_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
            Point p4 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(s_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
            Core.line(histImage, p3, p4, GREEN, 2, 8, 0);

            Point p5 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(v_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
            Point p6 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(v_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
            Core.line(histImage, p5, p6, BLUE, 2, 8, 0);

        }

        Highgui.imwrite("img-histogram.jpg", histImage);
        System.out.println("Hist size is: " + hsv_planes.size());

        List<Mat> histograms = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        histograms.add(h_hist);
        histograms.add(s_hist);
        histograms.add(v_hist);

        return histograms;
    }

    public Mat identifyLowSat(Mat image) {

        Mat hsvTargetImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, hsvTargetImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        List<Mat> hsv_planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        Core.split(hsvTargetImage, hsv_planes);

        //Get saturation channel
        Mat s_hist = hsv_planes.get(1);

        Imgproc.threshold(s_hist, s_hist, 65, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-saturation.png", s_hist);

        return s_hist;
    }

    public Mat getBackProjOfHueTemplate(Mat image, Mat hue_histogram) {

        Mat hsvTargetImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, hsvTargetImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        List<Mat> hsv_planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        Core.split(hsvTargetImage, hsv_planes);

        Mat backProj = new Mat();
        final MatOfFloat range = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);

        Imgproc.calcBackProject(hsv_planes, new MatOfInt(0), hue_histogram, backProj, range, 4);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-backProj.png", backProj);

        return backProj;
    }

    public Mat meanShift(Mat image) {
        Mat map = new Mat();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        TermCriteria term = new TermCriteria();

        term.maxCount = 100;
        term.type = TermCriteria.EPS;
        term.epsilon = 0.1;

        Imgproc.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, map, 0.5, 0.5, 5, term);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-meanshift.png", map);
        return map;
    }

    public MatOfDMatch filterMatches(Mat img1, Mat img2) {

        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);
        DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRISK);
        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

        // First photo
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
        descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

        // Second photo
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
        descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

        // Matching
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
        MatOfDMatch filteredMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
        matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

        List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
        Double max_dist = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        Double min_dist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

        for (DMatch matchesList1 : matchesList) {
            Double dist = (double) matchesList1.distance;
            if (dist < min_dist) {
                min_dist = dist;
            }
            if (dist > max_dist) {
                max_dist = dist;
            }
        }

        LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
        for (DMatch matchesList1 : matchesList) {
            if (matchesList1.distance <= (1.5 * min_dist)) {
                good_matches.addLast(matchesList1);
            }
        }

        MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
        //goodMatches.fromList(good_matches);
        List<DMatch> newGood_Matches = subListGoodMatches(good_matches);
        goodMatches.fromList(newGood_Matches);

        //put keypoints mats into lists
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints1_List = keypoints1.toList();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints2_List = keypoints2.toList();

        //put keypoints into point2f mats so calib3d can use them to find homography
        LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>();
        LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < newGood_Matches.size(); i++) {
            objList.addLast(keypoints2_List.get(newGood_Matches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
            sceneList.addLast(keypoints1_List.get(newGood_Matches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        }
        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
        obj.fromList(objList);
        scene.fromList(sceneList);

        System.out.println(matches.size() + " " + goodMatches.size());

        //output image
        Mat outputImg = new Mat();
        MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
        Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, goodMatches, outputImg, Scalar.all(-1), Scalar.all(-1), drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-matches.png", outputImg);
        drawWithRect(img1, img2, obj, scene, outputImg);

        keypointers1 = keypoints1;
        keypointers2 = keypoints2;

        return goodMatches;
    }

    public MatOfDMatch filterMatchesByHomography(MatOfDMatch matches) {
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = keypointers1;
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = keypointers2;

        List<Point> lp1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Point> lp2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

        KeyPoint[] k1 = keypoints1.toArray();
        KeyPoint[] k2 = keypoints2.toArray();

        List<DMatch> matches_original = matches.toList();

        if (matches_original.size() < 4) {
            MatOfDMatch mat = new MatOfDMatch();
            return mat;
        }

        // Add matches keypoints to new list to apply homography
        for (DMatch match : matches_original) {
            Point kk1 = k1[match.queryIdx].pt;
            Point kk2 = k2[match.trainIdx].pt;
            lp1.add(kk1);
            lp2.add(kk2);
        }

        //srcPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(lp1.toArray(new Point[0]));
        //dstPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(lp2.toArray(new Point[0]));

        Mat mask = new Mat();
        //Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, Calib3d.LMEDS, 0.2, mask);
        List<DMatch> matches_homo = new ArrayList<DMatch>();
        int size = (int) mask.size().height;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (mask.get(i, 0)[0] == 1) {
                DMatch d = matches_original.get(i);
                matches_homo.add(d);
            }
        }

        MatOfDMatch mat = new MatOfDMatch();
        mat.fromList(matches_homo);

        //Highgui.imwrite("img-matchesWithRect.png", mat);
        return mat;
    }

    public void drawMatches(Mat img1, Mat img2, MatOfDMatch matches, boolean imageOnly) {
        Mat out = new Mat();

        MatOfKeyPoint key2 = keypointers2;
        MatOfKeyPoint key1 = keypointers1;

        //Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, im1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, im2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        if (imageOnly) {
            MatOfDMatch emptyMatch = new MatOfDMatch();
            MatOfKeyPoint emptyKey1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
            MatOfKeyPoint emptyKey2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
            Features2d.drawMatches(img1, emptyKey1, img2, emptyKey2, emptyMatch, out);
        } else {
            Features2d.drawMatches(img1, key1, img2, key2, matches, out);
        }

        //Imgproc.cvtColor(out, out, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        Core.putText(out, "FRAME", new Point(img1.width() / 2, 30), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, new Scalar(0, 255, 255), 3);
        Core.putText(out, "MATCHED", new Point(img1.width() + img2.width() / 2, 30), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-drawnMatches.png", out);
    }

    public void drawWithRect(Mat img1, Mat img2, MatOfPoint2f obj, MatOfPoint2f scene, Mat outputImg){
        //run homography on object and scene points
        Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC, 5);
        Mat tmp_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

        //get corners from object
        tmp_corners.put(0, 0, new double[]{0, 0});
        tmp_corners.put(1, 0, new double[]{img2.cols(), 0});
        tmp_corners.put(2, 0, new double[]{img2.cols(), img2.rows()});
        tmp_corners.put(3, 0, new double[]{0, img2.rows()});

        Core.perspectiveTransform(tmp_corners, scene_corners, H);

        Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(0, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(1, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(1, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(2, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(2, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(3, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line(outputImg, new Point(scene_corners.get(3, 0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(0, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

        Highgui.imwrite("img-matchesWithRect.png", outputImg);
    }
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.load(new File("/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java249.dylib").getAbsolutePath());

        Mat img1 = Highgui.imread(scenesD);
        Mat img2 = Highgui.imread(objectD);

        MeanShift Tester = new MeanShift();
        List<Mat> histogramsList;
        Mat hue_histogram;
        Mat saturationChannel;
        Mat getBackProjOfHueTemp;

        //Calulate Histogram of Object
        histogramsList = Tester.calculateHistograms(img2);

        //Get saturation channel of scene
        saturationChannel = Tester.identifyLowSat(img1);

        //Get hue of calculated object histogram
        hue_histogram = histogramsList.get(0);

        //Get back projection of object from calculated hue histogram template
        getBackProjOfHueTemp = Tester.getBackProjOfHueTemplate(img2, hue_histogram);

        //Filtering matches
        MatOfDMatch matches = Tester.filterMatches(saturationChannel, getBackProjOfHueTemp);
        MatOfDMatch homo_matches = Tester.filterMatchesByHomography(matches);

        //Draw img unto screen;
        Tester.drawMatches(saturationChannel, getBackProjOfHueTemp, homo_matches, false);
    }
```

And so far here's the final image i get (img-matches.png)
[image]

And trying to get the rect from the image gives me this (img-matchesWithRect.png)
[image]

Comment: @mprat I did that implemented it in my drawMatches() method and did the homography in the drawMacthesWithRect()

Comment: Your question is unclear - what exactly is the problem? Error messages? Cases where it doesn't work? Have you tried it on a small example?

Comment: State it in my post "My question is how do I get the sub image from the target image?"

Comment: It seems that you are using a very small number of keypoints. Have you tried with a larger number of good matches?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you have the `Point`s in your original image that you found have matches in your target image. These points all have `x` and `y` coordinates - to find the "subimage" (or a rectangle in the image), all you need to do is take the minimum of all the `x`'s to get your top left `x` coordinate, the minimum of the `y`s to get your top left `y` coordinate, the max of the `x`s to get your bottom right `x` coordinate, and the max of the `y`s to get your bottom right `y` coordinate.

Then with these you can create a `Rect` (http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Rect.html) and use it to access the subimage: image(Rect) (assuming you have a previous variable `image` that is a `Mat`):

```
Rect sub_rect = new Rect(min_x, min_y, max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y);
Mat sub_region = image(sub_rect);
```

Now `sub_region` will have your subregion in it.

Comment: could you give a code sample in java? That would be helpful been trying to convert from C++ to Java all day from the openCV docs

Comment: You should explain how, or what the error message was, or what you did. Just saying it doesn't work doesn't help.